# why is my data not being updated?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-1.8

this is model for the database, the user changes the importance, and according to the level the user chooses, a score/point is to assigned 
but all it shows is 300 for my_points and 0 for their_points no matter what is chosen.

```
 from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
# Create your models here.
class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    draft = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    #answers = models.ManyToManyField('Answer')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.text[:10]


class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)


    def __unicode__(self): #def __str__(self):
        return self.text[:10]
LEVELS = (
    ('Mandatory', 'Mandatory'),
    ('Very Important', 'Very Important'),
    ('Somewhat Important', 'Somewhat Important'),
    ('Not Important', 'Not Important'),
    )

class UserAnswer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    my_answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, related_name = 'user_answer')
    my_answer_importance = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices= LEVELS)
    my_points = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
    their_answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, null=True, blank=True, related_name = 'match_answer')
    their_importance = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices= LEVELS)
    their_points = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.my_answer.text[:10]

def score_importance(importance_level):
    if importance_level == "Mandatory":
        points = 300
    elif importance_level == "Very Important":
        points = 200
    elif importance_level == "Somewhat Important":
        points = 50
    elif importance_level == "Not Important":
        points = 0
    else:
        points = 0
    return points


def update_user_answer_score(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    #print sender
    print instance
    #print created
    if instance.my_points == -1:
        my_points = score_importance(instance.my_answer_importance)
        instance.my_points = my_points
        print my_points
        instance.save()
    if instance.their_points == -1:
        their_points = score_importance(instance.their_importance)
        instance.their_points = their_points
        print my_points
        instance.save()


post_save.connect(update_user_answer_score, sender=UserAnswer)
```

Comment: Why have you done this? Since the points always depends on the importance level, why not have a single integer field with the text as descriptions and the points as the value?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is needlessly complicated. You really don't need separated `my_points` and `my_answer_importance` fields and the way you are using choices, kind of beats the whole point of using choices. I propose you change your code like this:

```
LEVELS = (
    (300, 'Mandatory'),
    (200, 'Very Important'),
    (50, 'Somewhat Important'),
    (0, 'Not Important'),
    )

class UserAnswer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    my_answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, related_name = 'user_answer')
    my_points = models.IntegerField(default=-1, choices=LEVELS)
    their_answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, null=True, blank=True, related_name = 'match_answer')
    their_points = models.IntegerField(default=-1, choices=LEVELS)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.my_answer.text[:10]
```

Now you don't need your signal and that entire code block can be removed.

Comment: i need to save it to my database,and im following a tutorial, so going according to it. is there anything wrong with my above code?

Comment: yes, that's what I have said in my answer. Not all tutorials are equal. Some tutorials are absolute rubbish.

Comment: i am creating a choice for the user to select his/her importance level and the level of the person/he she wants to match with. and you code gave me error too . please see this https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/matchmaker-2/blob/bb3eac029ac2b5fbb7c880c6d1f1dada2decd23d/src/questions/models.py

Comment: never use the term 'gives an error' here on stackoverflow. Always state the exact error.

Comment: And also please dont' expect answerers here to go through documents on third party websites just to answer our question. Post everything relevent as part of your question.

Comment: sorry, but i used the logic, i even printed the importance level. it prints the correct level that i chose, but, i think there is a problem with my score_importance function, as the correct value is not being assigned

Comment: As I mentioned your score_importance_function is obsolete.